# Monitor data changes for dynamically modified list of IDs

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin, signalr, sqldependency

I'm trying hard to figure out best possible solution for my case. Suppose I have a table in an MSSQL database over which I want to track changes and, in the event of a change, send new data using SignalR to my Xamarin application.

**Problem one**: Due to the relatively high traffic, I am looking for an ideal solution in terms of performance. For this reason, I decided that it would be best to track changes only over records that the user is currently eavesdropping on (it is in the product detail in the Xamarin application).

**Problem two**: So after quite a long study, I finally chose SqlTableDependency instead of MS SqlDependency. There I managed to provide a filter with a list of current IDs for SqlTableDependcy. However, whenever I modified the filter (removed or added an ID), I had to stop the service, create a new instance with the new filter, and restart it. Which I find unsatisfactory.

**Final question**: Is there a way I can track changes only over certain records and at the same time dynamically edit the list of current IDs?

Comment: You can add a version to the IDs. Then get the veision before setting and set the version after setting.